# How to edit datagridview using SqlCeDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I've a frmEdit with datagridview that's bouned to this:

```
string sqlqry1 = "select p_Name from Items where p_Id=" + p_Id;
        using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sqlqry1, conn))
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(dt1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
        }
```

How to edit cells and save them back to the db?, tried using this:

```
using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sqlqry1, conn))
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(dt1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
            a.Update(dt1);
        }
```

Nothing.

Is there anyway?.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution:

```
        SqlCeDataAdapter da;
        SqlCeCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;


        da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from Items", conn);
        cmdBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Fill(myDatabaseDataSet, "Items");
        myDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Items"].Rows[0]["p_Name"] = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["p_Name"].Value.ToString();
        da.Update(myDatabaseDataSet, "Items");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dT;
BindingSource bS;

using (SqlCeConnection yourConnection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\YourDatabase.sdf"))
{
    dT = new DataTable();
    bS = new BindingSource();    

    string query = "SELECT * FROM table01";
    SqlCeDataAdapter dA = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, yourConnection);
    SqlCeCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dA);
    dA.Fill(dT);

    bS.DataSource = dT;
    dgv01.DataSource = bS;
}
```

Resurrecting this with a working example because of this pages rank on google.